# Plot model doesn't show layers of model, only the model name

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.x

I'm trying to build some model using TensorFlow2, so I create a class of my model as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class Dummy(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, name="dummy"):
        super(Dummy, self).__init__()
        self._name = name

        self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax)

    def call(self, inputs, training=False):
        x = self.dense1(inputs)
        return self.dense2(x)

model = Dummy()
model.build(input_shape=(None,5))
```

Now I want to plot the model, while using `summary()` returns what I expect, `plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, expand_nested=True)` return only a block with the model name.

How can I return the graph of my model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Francois Chollet says the following:

> You can do all these things (printing input / output shapes) in a
>   Functional or Sequential model because these models are static graphs
>   of layers.
>
> In contrast, a subclassed model is a piece of Python code (a call
>   method). There is no graph of layers here. We cannot know how layers
>   are connected to each other (because that's defined in the body of
>   call, not as an explicit data structure), so we cannot infer input /
>   output shapes.

There are two solutions to this:

1. Either you build your model sequentially/using the Functional api.
2. You wrap your '`call`' function into a Functional Model like here:

`class Subclass(Model)`:

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
def call(self, x):
    ...

def model(self):
    x = Input(shape=(24, 24, 3))
    return Model(inputs=[x], outputs=self.call(x))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sub = subclass()
    sub.model().summary()
```

Answer is taken from here:[model.summary() can't print output shape while using subclass model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235212/model-summary-cant-print-output-shape-while-using-subclass-model)

Also, this is a good article read: https://medium.com/tensorflow/what-are-symbolic-and-imperative-apis-in-tensorflow-2-0-dfccecb01021