# Square brackets in keras model output shape

Tags: keras

I've recently encountered this when looking at a model's summary.

[image]

I was wondering, what's the difference between `[(None, 16)]` and `(None, 16)`? Why does the Input layer have such input shape?

Source: [model.summary() can't print output shape while using subclass model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235212/model-summary-cant-print-output-shape-while-using-subclass-model)

Comment: Can you please also add the code for model definition that you have used ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235212/model-summary-cant-print-output-shape-while-using-subclass-model

It's the last comment from this post.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is how you are defining the input_shape. A single element tuple in python is actually a scalar value as you can see below -

```
input_shape0 = 32
input_shape1 = (32)
input_shape2 = (32,)
print(input_shape0, input_shape1, input_shape2)
```

```
32 32 (32,)
```

Since Keras function API `Input` needs an input shape as a tuple, you will have to pass it in the form of `(n,)` instead of `n`

It's weird that you get a square bracket because when I run the exact same code, I get an error.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-828-b564be68c80d> in <module>
     33 
     34 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 35     mlp = MLP((16))
     36     mlp.summary()

<ipython-input-828-b564be68c80d> in __init__(self, input_shape, **kwargs)
      6         super(MLP, self).__init__(**kwargs)
      7         # Add input layer
----> 8         self.input_layer = klayers.Input(input_shape)
      9 
     10         self.dense_1 = klayers.Dense(64, activation='relu')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_layer.py in Input(shape, batch_size, name, dtype, sparse, tensor, **kwargs)
    229       dtype=dtype,
    230       sparse=sparse,
--> 231       input_tensor=tensor)
    232   # Return tensor including `_keras_history`.
    233   # Note that in this case train_output and test_output are the same pointer.

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_layer.py in __init__(self, input_shape, batch_size, dtype, input_tensor, sparse, name, **kwargs)
     89     if input_tensor is None:
     90       if input_shape is not None:
---> 91         batch_input_shape = (batch_size,) + tuple(input_shape)
     92       else:
     93         batch_input_shape = None

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Therefore, the right way to do it (which should fix your model summary as well is as below -

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers as klayers

class MLP(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, input_shape=(32,), **kwargs):
        super(MLP, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # Add input layer
        self.input_layer = klayers.Input(input_shape)

        self.dense_1 = klayers.Dense(64, activation='relu')
        self.dense_2 = klayers.Dense(10)

        # Get output layer with `call` method
        self.out = self.call(self.input_layer)

        # Reinitial
        super(MLP, self).__init__(
            inputs=self.input_layer,
            outputs=self.out,
            **kwargs)

    def build(self):
        # Initialize the graph
        self._is_graph_network = True
        self._init_graph_network(
            inputs=self.input_layer,
            outputs=self.out
        )

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.dense_1(inputs)
        return self.dense_2(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mlp = MLP((16,))
    mlp.summary()
```

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_19 (InputLayer)        (None, 16)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 64)                1088      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 10)                650       
=================================================================
Total params: 1,738
Trainable params: 1,738
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: with TF 2.3 and 2.4 i still get the square brackets with akshay sehgal's example above:  "[(None, 16)]"  :(