# `model.summary()` with TensorFlow model subclassing print output shape as "multiple"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model, subclass

I tried to implement Vgg network with following VggBlock.

```py
class VggBlock(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, filters, repetitions):
    super(VggBlock, self).__init__()
    self.repetitions = repetitions

    self.conv_layers = [Conv2D(filters=filters, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu') for _ in range(repetitions)]
    self.max_pool = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))

  def call(self, inputs):
    x = inputs
    for layer in self.conv_layers:
      x = layer(x)
    return self.max_pool(x)

test_block = VggBlock(filters=64, repetitions=2)
temp_inputs = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
test_block(temp_inputs)
test_block.summary()
```

Then the above code prints:

```
Model: "vgg_block"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d (Conv2D)             multiple                  1792      
                                                                 
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           multiple                  36928     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D  multiple                 0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 38,720
Trainable params: 38,720
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

And if I build Vgg with these blocks, its `summary()` also prints "multiple".

There are some questions similar to my problem, ex:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/13782 ,
[model.summary() can't print output shape while using subclass model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235212/model-summary-cant-print-output-shape-while-using-subclass-model)

However, I can not extend the answers in the second link: in terms of varying `input_shape`.

How do I treat `summary()` in order to make "multiple" to be an appropriate shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already linked some workarounds. You seem to be landing [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/e6784e4302c7b8cd116b74a784f4b78d60e83c26/keras/utils/layer_utils.py#L363), because the output shape of each layer cannot be determined. As stated [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25036#issuecomment-504125711):

> You can do all these things (printing input / output shapes) in a
> Functional or Sequential model because these models are static graphs
> of layers.
>
> In contrast, a subclassed model is a piece of Python code (a call
> method). There is no graph of layers here. We cannot know how layers
> are connected to each other (because that's defined in the body of
> call, not as an explicit data structure), so we cannot infer input /
> output shapes.

You could also try something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class VggBlock(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self, filters, repetitions, image_shape):
    super(VggBlock, self).__init__()
    self.repetitions = repetitions

    self.conv_layers = [tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=filters, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu') for _ in range(repetitions)]
    self.max_pool = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))

    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=image_shape)
    x = inputs
    for layer in self.conv_layers:
      x = layer(x)
    outputs = self.max_pool(x)
    self.model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

  def call(self, inputs):
    return self.model(inputs)
  
  def summary(self):
    self.model.summary()

test_block = VggBlock(filters=64, repetitions=2, image_shape=(224, 224, 3))
test_block.summary()
```

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
                                                                 
 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
                                                                 
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D  (None, 112, 112, 64)     0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 38,720
Trainable params: 38,720
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```